# WebAPI 2 Authorize Roles with MSAL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm in throws of moving our security architecture from ASP.NET Core Identity to Azure AD V2 with MSAL.js. We used a lot of Roles with the ASP.NET Core Identity implementation and the information was managed in the database using the web application. The pattern I'm abandoning is similar to this one.

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/role-based-security

Azure AD with MSAL is working. The tokens are being created and passed and the local Web API Endpoints decorated with the generic `[Authorize]` attribute are being honored as you would expect. Web API Endpoints decorated with `[Authorize(Roles= "Fee, Foo, Fi, Fum")]` are throwing a 401 unauthorized error.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I write a CustomAuthorize attribute override for Web API and go back to the database and grab the roles. (probably match the DB defined roles to the user based on email address)

**OR**

Is there a way to implement roles natively with Azure AD V2?

I'm not sure whats the best course of action from here. Documentation and Code samples seem limited. It would sure be nice to just throw a AD User in a Group and have the Group be respected as a Role in the Web API. On the other hand, It's nice to have Role delegation handled within the confines of the Web Application.

Any advice, experience or interest would be greatly appreciated.

**Answer**

Follow up to my question. @Marc , You're correct, after looking at the token the Roles are not present. Adding Roles to the token seems pretty straight forward. You need to Patch the graph schema to include them, Configure the roles and assign them to users as needed thru AAD.

Or that's how it looks at first glance. After digging a deeper, it requires a P1 or P2 Enterprise license which *only* costs an additional 6$ per month per user. This will literally double the cost of hosting email in the cloud for us.

Alternatively I wrote a CustomAuthAttribute for WebAPI and tied User & Roles together on the server backend. Roles can still be managed via the web application and users can still login using Active Directory Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that the id token returned in implicit flow (the one you use with JS) does not include app roles (or groups). I cannot find any docs confirming that but [see others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041125/how-do-you-read-roles-permissions-using-msal-angular) who got around the issue (so the issue must be there) by using Graph to get the roles (or groups).

You can capture the token you receive from AAD and view it using https://jwt.ms to see whether roles are included in it.