# Getting group and role information from microsoft adal + spring boot integration with azure active directory

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, ms-adal-angular

I'm integrating azure active directory using microsoft adal and spring boot. Now I'm only getting information of user only. I need to get the group as well as role information also. What are the steps I need to take care off. Any help would be appreciable.

```
app.module.ts
-----------------

function initializer(adalService: MsAdalAngular6Service) {
      return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (adalService.isAuthenticated) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          adalService.login();
        }
      });
    }

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
          tenant: 'xxxbef18-40f6-44e6-972c-407462a99xxx',
          clientId: 'xxx4602f-e3c8-4114-ae23-42bf9e57dxxx',
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
          navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
          cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
      })
      ],
      providers: [ {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initializer,
        multi: true,
        deps: [MsAdalAngular6Service]
      },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
          multi: true
        }],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Getting the user information from below code

```
this.adalService.userInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call MS Graph to get user, roles, and groups. And you will need to add required permissions to your scope in the `API permissions` of the portal.

**Note:** About the permission you need to add, you could refer to [user permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions), [group permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions), and [role permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#permissions).

```
    // get user
    let graphUser = await graphClient.api('/me').get();

    // get groups by user_id
    let graphUserGroups = await graphClient.api('/users/${graphUser.id}').get();

    // get roles by user_id
    let graphRoles = await graphClient.Users["${graphUser.id}"].AppRoleAssignments.Request().GetAsync();
```

There is the issue about reading roles by msal-angular, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049063/13308381).

Comment: Thanks pamela, what I really need is a sample that integrates with 'microsoft-adal-angular6' library and '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'. Can I use the same accessToken returned from 'adal'.

Comment: @MelvinMoses The code is based on JavaScript, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request), and it is for your issue.